# Getting org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException

Tags: automated-testing, selenium-webdriver, java

I'm getting `org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException` error.

My code is:

```
@Test(priority = 3)
public void transactionCancel() throws Exception {
    WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 60);
    wait.until(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfElementLocated(By.cssSelector(MyLocators.Transaction_btnBuy)));
    WebElement button = driver.findElement(By.cssSelector(MyLocators.Transaction_btnBuy));
    button.click();

    //popup window handling
    Set<String> allHandle = driver.getWindowHandles(); // Fetch all handles
    Iterator<String> iterator = allHandle.iterator();
    Object popupR = new Object();
    while (iterator.hasNext()) {
        popupR = iterator.next();
    }
    driver.switchTo().window((String) popupR); // switch to popup
    String parentWindowHandler = new String();
    driver.switchTo().window(parentWindowHandler);

    wait.until(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfElementLocated(By.xpath(MyLocators.Transaction_popupCancel)));
    button = driver.findElement(By.xpath(MyLocators.Transaction_popupCancel));
    button.click();

}
```

Comment: Which line is throwing the exception? Also, what is the full stack dump?

Comment: Where you got an issue

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The string parentWindowHandler is not assigned a value. 
So the line `driver.switchTo().window(parentWindowHandler);`
will not work.